# Convert a decimal number to a hexadecimal string in Assembly

Tags: assembly, hex, decimal

What I need to do is to create an assembly source file (2hex.s), to be able to use it on a C program (test2hex.c). In 2hex.s, I need to create a function to turn the decimal number to a hexadecimal string.

Here is the test2hex.c file:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void tohex(long x);

int main{
    tohex(1);    //Output: 0000000000000001
    tohex(1035); //Output: 000000000000040B
    tohex(-2);   //Output: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I need to create a 2hex.s file to print those outputs. I am not sure how I can do this. Here is my attempt at it:

```
    .global tohex
    .text
tohex:
    xor     %r10,%r10
    mov     $16, %r11
    mov     %rdi, %rax
    cqto
next:
    idiv    %r11
    cmp     $10, %rdx
    jg      lttrs
    mov     %rdx,%rcx
    add     $48,%rcx
    mov     %rcx, %rdi
    call    putchar
    inc     %r10
    cmp     $15, %r10
    jle     next
    jmp     exit
lttrs:
    mov     %rdx, %rcx
    add     $55, %rcx
    mov     %rcx, %rdi
    call    putchar
    inc     %r10
    cmp     $15, %r10
    jle     next
    jmp     exit
exit:
    ret
```

At first I was actually able to get the letter B when I run the second function (tohex(1035)) without the 16 times loop. However, using the loop seems to have caused a floating point exception error.

Also one more thing, I can guess that the result would come in the reverse order of what I need, so what would I need to do for that?

Help me out please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, we aren't a Gimme the Codez homework site. You need to make an attempt at solving this yourself. Produce some code, let us know what you tried and what didn't work and we may be able to help you on specific problems. Read about good question writing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's a good idea for questions like this to specify what assembly language you are coding for, the assembler you are using, and the OS you are writing it for.This type of information+effort might attract the attention of some of us so that we may be able to assist you.Good luck!

Comment: I will offer up some advice. Take a piece of paper and see how you would take a decimal number and methodically break it down by dividing by 10 until there are no digits left in the number(A similar thing can be done by dividing by 16 to do hexadecimal). When you have an idea on paper try to write it in a higher level language like C, Pascal, Basic etc. Once you have working code for a higher level language then translate it to assembly language.

Comment: I have edited my post. As you can see I have basically used the same idea as you suggested earlier. I have been working on this for the past 5 hours and this is the best I got so far. I am very easily able to this on Python and Java, but Assembly is just more difficult.

Comment: apparently someone gave me a clue that may be shift instructions would be better, I am not sure how though, shift instructions never got into my head till now.

Comment: You need to `cqto` before each division, not just the first one. Although using `idiv` is completely unnecessary here, since you can divide by 16 by shifting 4 bits to the right (i.e. `shrq $4,%rax`). The remainder would be the result of ANDing with 15 prior to the shift.

Comment: Yes, that actually worked, but I am actually unsure of why ANDing gives me the remainder though. Thanks a lot anyways. :)